# How to print the following pattern in python

Tags: python

```
1
2 6
3 7 10
4 8 11 13
5 9 12 14 15
```

I have been trying for a long time but failing to make a code for it.
Please share a code for the above pattern because I'm struggling to make it out.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?  FWIW, this feels like it may be a homework question; [here is a good meta post on how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Post some code and we can give you hints.

Comment: What approach have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
l = [0, 4, 7, 9, 10]
for i in range(5):
     print(' '.join([str(i+1+l[e]) for e in range(i+1)]))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print('''1
2 6
3 7 10
4 8 11 13
5 9 12 14 15''')
```

Comment: Great! This runs in O(1) space and time complexity

Comment: @SandeepGusain Well to be fair, so do the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
for y in range(0,6): #height of right angled triangle
    z = y
    for x in range(0,y):
        if x ==0:
            print(z,end = ' ')
        else:
            z = z + (10 - (5+x)) #if you notice pattern its n n+4 n+3 n+2 .... so just implementing that
            print(z,end = ' ')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

**LOGIC**

```
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i){
    int k=i,m=0;
    for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
    {
        k=k-m;
        print(k);   
        k=k+5;
        m++;
    }   
    print("\n");
}
```

> Here is the logic, convert it to python equivalent syntax.